Explicitly showing examples of plurisubharmonicity
In light of the result that $-\log \delta_G$ is plurisubharmonic if and only if $G \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is a pseudoconvex domain where is $\delta_G = d(z,\mathbb{C}^n-G)$ is the boundary distance function on $G$, I wanted to show that the following functions are plurisubharmonic directly (to show that the respective domains are pseudoconvex).
(i) $-\log(1-||z||)$ for the unit ball $\mathbb{B}_n$
(ii) $\displaystyle -\log(\min_{1 \leq i \leq n}\{ 1-|z_i|\}) $ for the unit polydisc $\mathbb{D}^n$
I have no  idea so as to how to proceed. Could someone help? What properties/characterization could be useful here?
Thank you.
